# Selecting a menu type in a module

Tags: menu, module-params

For module parameters -
how to select the type of menu and link, how is it implemented in the administrative part, when creating a new menu?
[image: Screenshot]

---

I will clarify.
I need to insert a link into the url(text) field - like in the article editor - insert a menu / contact / article.

Comment: After reading your question, I am not sure what the actual question is. Do you mean creating a new menu item for a new menu and the type that you can select for instance?
Could you maybe clear it up by explaining what part 1 and part 2 are numbered in your question by editing it and this may help me answer it for you?

Comment: **Do you mean creating a new menu item for a new menu and the type that you can select for instance?** - no

Comment: I don't need to create a new menu.
In the parameters of the module is a field with type url - module_urls.
For this field, I need to call the dialog for selecting the types of menu items - articles, component links, internal and external links and insert this link in the module_urls.

Comment: Please take our [tour] to understand that Stack Exchange site has a strict Q&A format.  Page content is not ordered chronologically.  There must be a single question containing all question details and there may be one or more answers posted.  Each answer must attempt to resolve the posted question.  An answer that does not attempt to resolve the question is Not An Answer (in which case, the post may be moderated by other users to maintain clean site structure).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such default-form-field type ready to use in your xml in joomla! for those fields. You need to create your own custom form field type to have such a functionality / layout.